# When i send data to server firts time it is work fine, but next time it is not call getParams() metod

Tags: android, internet-connection

I used StringRequest for my project. When i send data to server firts time it is work fine, but next time it is not call getParams() metod. how ca i solve this problem

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("product_id", "18");
                        parameters.put("count", Productcount.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("type", cashstatus);
                        parameters.put("description", "Matn bo'ladi");
                        parameters.put("phone_number", "946287009");
                        parameters.put("on_map", address);
                        parameters.put("address", PersonAddresss.getText().toString());

                        try {
                            File toRead = new File(getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), "BCardParams");
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(toRead);
                            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                            HashMap<String, String> mapInFile = (HashMap<String, String>) ois.readObject();
                            ois.close();
                            fis.close();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : mapInFile.entrySet()) {
                                Log.d("LOG____", m.getKey() + " : " + m.getValue());
                                parameters.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return parameters;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                request.setRetryPolicy(new

                        DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

                );

                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: You have to provide some code in order to have us help you

Comment: provide some code and which library you have been using to do this.

Comment: code, please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all people, how want to help me. I find answer for my question. There have error because I create RequestQueue inside of activity, and every time i want to send data to server new RequestQueue function create. We have to create RequestQueue one time and call it, not create new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

please try changing this

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new
                        DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
                        0,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
                );
```

Comment: Thanks your attention. I try your code, but it is not help me.

Comment: programm didn't get error. It is get server's old responce, I checked and i find getParams() not working

Comment: programm work one time only. and other request it is get first responce

Comment: well have you tried putting that request in REST Client , as your parameters  uses only count and address as varying value rest value are static